# How to properly convert dataframe from integer to numeric in R?

Tags: r

I have an abundance dataframe improved as a csv with column and row headers. When imported, and running `str(data)` it shows each row as int. I can't use vegan's package `specaccum` unless the data is numeric. After converting my dataframe into numeric it is still producing the following error:

```
Error in colSums(x) : 'x' must be numeric
```

My sample and code:

Structure of my dataframe before any conversion:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   180 obs. of  727 variables:
 $ Sample                 : Factor w/ 180 levels "Sample1","Sample2",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Abrostola              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Abrus                  : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Acanthamoeba           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Acanthopagrus          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Acetilactobacillus     : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Acetobacter            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Then:

```
data2 <- data[-1] ## to get rid of factor column
data2 <- lapply(data2, as.numeric)
> str(data2)
List of 726
 $ Abrostola              : num [1:180] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Abrus                  : num [1:180] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Acanthamoeba           : num [1:180] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Acanthopagrus          : num [1:180] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Acetilactobacillus     : num [1:180] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Acetobacter            : num [1:180] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Achromobacter          : num [1:180] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Acinetobacter          : num [1:180] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Next I tried running the very basic vegan command:

```
mycurve <- specaccum(comm = data2, method = "random", permutations = "1000")
```

But it gives the same error. I don't get it - my df is clearly converted to numeric so what is the issue??

**EDIT**

Prior to fixing my dataframe into numeric, I was using:

```
mycurve <- specaccum(comm = data[-1], method = "random", permutations = "1000") ## without prior removal of factor column
```

But it was giving the following error:

```
Error in nperm + EPS : non-numeric argument to binary operator
$ Acetobacter            : num [1:180] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I am not sure why it is targeting this particular column, it looks exactly the same as everything else. No columns are empty (i.e. no column sums equal 0 as I thought that would be causing an issue). I checked for weird symbols/whitespace - the columns do not have anything out of the ordinary. There are no empty cells either with "NA".

Output of `dput(head(data))` but due to body limit in this post I had to truncate the output.

```
structure(list(Sample = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Sample1", "Sample2", 
"Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", "Sample180"), class = "factor"), Abrostola = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Abrus = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Acanthamoeba = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Acanthopagrus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), Acetilactobacillus = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Acetobacter = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Achromobacter = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), Acinetobacter = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Acipenser = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Acomys = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Acremonium = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Acromyrmex = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Acropora = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Actinidia = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Actinobacillus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Acyrthosiphon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Acytostelium = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Aedes = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Aegilops = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Aeromonas = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L
    ), Ageratum = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Aggregatibacter = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Albugo = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Alcaligenes = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Alcanivorax = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Allygidius = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Amblyraja = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Amoebogregarina = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Amphidinium = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), Amphiprion = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Amphipyra = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Amycolatopsis = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), Ananas = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Anas = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Andhravirus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Andrena = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Anolis = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Anopheles = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Anoplophora = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Anoxybacillus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), Anthocharis = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Aphanomyces = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Aphyllon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Apilactobacillus = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Apotomis = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Apteryx = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Aquila = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Arabidopsis = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Arabis = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Arachis = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Arctia = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**SOLVED**

While the code I was using for mycurve was working with other method options and quoting permutations, simply removing the quotes for permutations along with method random worked. Did not even need to convert the data into numeric.

```
mycurve <- specaccum(comm = data[-1], method = "random", permutations = 1000) ## REMOVED QUOTES IN PERMUTATIONS and used with INT dataframe
```

Comment: try: `specaccum(comm = data[[-1]], method = "random", permutations = "1000")`

Comment: Didn't work. Shows ```Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  attempt to select more than one element in get1index <real>```

Comment: could you `dput(head(data)` please.

Comment: See update above

Comment: I think your `data2` is a `list` object. Please convert it to a `dataframe`.

Comment: Oh yea I didn't catch that. I converted it into a dataframe of numeric but the original error came back! see my post for an update of what I just did.

Comment: Actually I realized again I did a mistake in converting to a dataframe, it is introducing an index column. Gotta fix this...removed my previous update for now.

Comment: `method = 'random'` is causing the error for this dataset.  `method` other than `random` like `exact`, `rarefaction`, `coleman` are working fine even before converting to numeric.

Comment: You are right! Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?specaccum`

> permutations - Number of permutations with method = "random". Usually an integer giving the number permutations, but can also be a list of control values for the permutations as returned by the function how, or a permutation matrix where each row gives the permuted indices.

```
 specaccum(comm = data[-1], method = "random", permutations = 1000)
```

-ouput

```
Species Accumulation Curve
Accumulation method: random, with 719 permutations
Call: specaccum(comm = data[-1], method = "random", permutations = 1000) 

                                                        
Sites    1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 5.000000  6
Richness 3.502086 5.731572 7.297636 8.598053 9.831711 11
sd       1.894776 1.483049 1.228892 1.143491 0.897720  0
```

Comment: This didn't work either. I didn't write this before but it was giving a previous error. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: @CuriousDude please check the inputs.  it should be integer/numeric for `permutations`

Comment: Updated the post with your dput input

Comment: They are int. Even after converting to numeric and ensuring my str(data2) is a data.frame of numeric values, the error persists. It is only doing this with the "random" option for method.

Comment: @CuriousDude Please check the changes I made `permutations = 1000` and not `permutations = "1000"`

Comment: That worked...wow I was following a fairly recent tutorial on this where permutations is quoted. It works for other methods I was clueluess that quoting permutations would suddenly cause such an error....quite odd to me. Thank you so much,